# Moving a curve inside a figure

Tags: matlab, user-interface, figure

[image][image]

As you can see, in the first picture I have two subplots, two the same, with the same curve position. But I need to change the curve position/or view angle of one of the subplot (doesn't matter now if the left one or the right one). The only working command is *CameraViewAngle* but it changes for both of it, I don't know why, and I need to be able to change for each one seperately. [image] 
As you can see in picture two, the view angle changes for both of it. I would rather chagne only the curve position.

The code I'm using is:

```
function [pointsQRS, pointsP, pointsT] = VCG (pointsQRS,pointsP,pointsT)


global ax1 ax2 h

figure('Name','Vektorkardiogram','NumberTitle','off','Color',[0.8 0.8 0.8])
ax1=subplot(1,2,1)
set(ax1,'Position',[0.10,0.11,0.3346590909090909,0.815],'CameraPosition',
[50.197132152696216,49.50150052184264,-7.57531754730548],'CameraTarget',
[0.4, 0.7, -0.33],'View',[-184.4219, -8.9326],'CameraViewAngle',
[9.256133109732078])

title('Vektorkardiogram')
hold on
grid on
view(3)

for i=2:size(pointsQRS,1)
if mod(i,2)==0
        QRS=plot3(pointsQRS([i-1:i],1),pointsQRS([i-1:i],2),pointsQRS([i-
1:i],3),'-g','LineWidth',1);
else
    plot3(pointsQRS([i-1:i],1),pointsQRS([i-1:i],2),pointsQRS([i-
1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
    end
end


for i=2:size(pointsT,1)
if mod(i,2)==0
    T=plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-1:i],3),'-
r','LineWidth',1);
else
    plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-1:i],3),'Color',
[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
end
end

for i=2:size(pointsP,1)
if mod(i,2)==0
     P=plot3(pointsP([i-1:i],1),pointsP([i-1:i],2),pointsP([i-1:i],3),'-
b','LineWidth',1);
else
    plot3(pointsP([i-1:i],1),pointsP([i-1:i],2),pointsP([i-1:i],3),'Color',
[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
end
end

xlabel('Vx');ylabel('Vy');zlabel('Vz');

 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[-0.5, 2, -1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, -0.5, -1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
 mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, 2, 1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);

text(-0.5, 2, -1, 'Vx','FontSize',12);  
text(1.5, -0.5, -1, 'Vy','FontSize',12); 
text(1.5, 2, 1, 'Vz','FontSize',12);







ax2=subplot(1,2,2)
set(ax2,'Position',[0.565,0.11,0.33465909090909096,0.815],'CameraPosition',
[-13.197132152696216,-59.50150052184264,10.57531754730548])

title('Vektorkardiogram')
hold on
grid on
h=linkprop([ax1, ax2],
{'CameraPosition','CameraUpVector','XTick','YTick','ZTick'});

for i=2:size(pointsQRS,1)
if mod(i,2)==0
    QRS=plot3(pointsQRS([i-1:i],1),pointsQRS([i-1:i],2),pointsQRS([i-
1:i],3),'-g','LineWidth',1);
else
    plot3(pointsQRS([i-1:i],1),pointsQRS([i-1:i],2),pointsQRS([i-
1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
end
end


for i=2:size(pointsT,1)
if mod(i,2)==0
    T=plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-1:i],3),'-
r','LineWidth',1);
else
    plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-1:i],3),'Color',
[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
end
end

for i=2:size(pointsP,1)
if mod(i,2)==0
     P=plot3(pointsP([i-1:i],1),pointsP([i-1:i],2),pointsP([i-1:i],3),'-
b','LineWidth',1);
else
    plot3(pointsP([i-1:i],1),pointsP([i-1:i],2),pointsP([i-1:i],3),'Color',
[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
end
end



xlabel('Vx');ylabel('Vy');zlabel('Vz');



   mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[-0.5, 2, -1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
   mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, -0.5, -1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
   mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, 2, 1], 'stemWidth', 
0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);

  text(-0.5, 2, -1, 'Vx','FontSize',12);  
  text(1.5, -0.5, -1, 'Vy','FontSize',12); 
  text(1.5, 2, 1, 'Vz','FontSize',12);


linkaxes([ax1, ax2])
```

I need it to change it in order to achieve 3D stereoscopic view using Google Cardboard.
Thank you in advance for any help!

PS: For example I want to achieve something as in the picture 3[image]
But in the picture three the 3D curves are not connected, by connected I mean that while I move with one of them, the other one will be moved in the same way.

[image]

Comment: Try without calling `linkaxes([ax1, ax2])`.

Comment: Works out, but a different problem occured, the left figure is way smaller.
See the edit in the question, last picture, the left figure/3D curve is way smaller.

Do you know why the picutre is smaller than the other one?

Comment: Can you please make your posted code executable on other machines? Put some data in `pointsQRS, pointsP, pointsT`, and give reference to `mArrow3` function.

Comment: You can download the mArrow3 function here: 
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25372-marrow3-m-easy-to-use-3d-arrow

The only change in my code for demonstration you can use following:
For the data I did:
    pointsQRS = 1:3:78;
    pointsP = 1:2:92;
    pointsT = 1:1:85;

The specific data I have selected it in my GUI, so I can't fill in exact data I'm using. But the angle of view is noticable as well with the axises done by the mArrow3 function.

Comment: I managed to get a partial solution, please let me know if it's still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to partially solve it.

Changing `CameraViewAngle`, modifies the size of the curve, so I decided to keep it unmodified.

Instead of setting the angle, set `CameraPosition` of `ax2` to be different than `ax1`, but keeping the same distance from the target.

Instead of using `linkprop`, I used [addlistener](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html), and implemented a callback function that sets the `CameraPosition` of `ax2` when `CameraPosition` of `ax1` is modified.

Read the following reference pages:

- [addlistener](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html)
- [View Control with the Camera Toolbar](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/view-control-with-the-camera-toolbar.html)
- [Camera Graphics Terminology](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/defining-scenes-with-camera-graphics.html)
- [Axes Properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html)
- [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html)

---

Here is the code:

```
function [pointsQRS, pointsP, pointsT] = VCG (pointsQRS,pointsP,pointsT)

%Clear global varabiles - for testing, we don't want any leftovers of ax1 and ax2.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
clear global
close all
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Set some input data.
pointsQRS = 1:3:78;
pointsP = 1:2:92;
pointsT = 1:1:85;


%global ax1 ax2 h

fig1 = figure('Name','Vektorkardiogram','NumberTitle','off','Color',[0.8 0.8 0.8]);
ax1=subplot(1,2,1);

%Don't use view command, fill all parameters manually.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%view(ax1, 3)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Set ax1 parameters values to be same as result as after executing view(ax1, 3)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
set(ax1, 'XLim', [-0.5, 2.0], 'YLim', [-1, 3.0], 'ZLim', [-1.5, 1.0]);
set(ax1, 'Position',[0.13, 0.11, 0.3346590909090909, 0.815]);
set(ax1, 'CameraViewAngle', 10.339584907201974);
set(ax1, 'CameraTarget', [0.75, 1.0, -0.25]);
set(ax1, 'View',[-184.4219, -8.9326]);
set(ax1, 'DataAspectRatio', [1, 1.6, 1.0]);
set(ax1, 'PlotBoxAspectRatio', [1, 0.95521169259094, 0.8871534463389812], 'PlotBoxAspectRatioMode', 'Manual');
set(ax1, 'CameraPosition', [-10.664276793913514,-22.800600208737055,10.57531754730548]);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


ax2 = subplot(1,2,2);

%Set ax2 parameters values to be same as result as after executing view(ax2, 3)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
set(ax2, 'XLim', [-0.5, 2.0], 'YLim', [-1, 3.0], 'ZLim', [-1.5, 1.0]);
set(ax2, 'Position',[0.5703409090909091, 0.11, 0.3346590909090909, 0.815]);
set(ax2, 'CameraViewAngle', 10.339584907201974);
set(ax2, 'CameraTarget', [0.75, 1.0, -0.25]);
set(ax2, 'View',[-184.4219, -8.9326]);
set(ax2, 'DataAspectRatio', [1, 1.6, 1.0]);
set(ax2, 'PlotBoxAspectRatio', [1, 0.95521169259094, 0.8871534463389812], 'PlotBoxAspectRatioMode', 'Manual');
set(ax2, 'CameraPosition', [-10.664276793913514,-22.800600208737055,10.57531754730548]);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%Move the camera of ax2 to be in different position compared to ax1, but keep the same distance from the Target.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
cameraTarget = [0.75, 1.0, -0.25];
cameraPosition = [-10.664276793913514,-22.800600208737055,10.57531754730548];
V = cameraPosition - cameraTarget;
newV = V + [-10, 0, 0];
newV = newV/norm(newV)*norm(V);
newCameraPosition = cameraTarget + newV;
set(ax2, 'CameraPosition', newCameraPosition);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Store ax1 and ax2 in figure UserData
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
set(fig1, 'UserData', [ax1, ax2]);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Set axes ax1 as active axes.
axes(ax1);


title('Vektorkardiogram')
hold on
grid on

%Move view(3) up
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%view(3)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Use plot3 from Matlab example (fill curve with some data).
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%t = -3*pi:pi/50:3*pi;st = sin(t)*2;ct = cos(t)*2;plot3(st,ct,t/6)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

for i=2:size(pointsQRS,1)
    if mod(i,2)==0
        QRS=plot3(pointsQRS([i-1:i],1),pointsQRS([i-1:i],2),pointsQRS([i-1:i],3),'-g','LineWidth',1);
    else
        plot3(pointsQRS([i-1:i],1),pointsQRS([i-1:i],2),pointsQRS([i-1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
    end
end


for i=2:size(pointsT,1)
    if mod(i,2)==0
        T=plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-1:i],3),'-r','LineWidth',1);
    else
        plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
    end
end

for i=2:size(pointsP,1)
    if mod(i,2)==0
        P=plot3(pointsP([i-1:i],1),pointsP([i-1:i],2),pointsP([i-1:i],3),'-b','LineWidth',1);
    else
        plot3(pointsP([i-1:i],1),pointsP([i-1:i],2),pointsP([i-1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
    end
end

xlabel('Vx');ylabel('Vy');zlabel('Vz');

mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[-0.5, 2, -1], 'stemWidth', 0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, -0.5, -1], 'stemWidth', 0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, 2, 1], 'stemWidth', 0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);

text(-0.5, 2, -1, 'Vx','FontSize',12);  
text(1.5, -0.5, -1, 'Vy','FontSize',12); 
text(1.5, 2, 1, 'Vz','FontSize',12);

%ax2 = subplot(1,2,2); Moved up, axes(ax2) is used instead.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%ax2 = subplot(1,2,2);
axes(ax2)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


title('Vektorkardiogram')
hold on
grid on

%Move linkprop to the end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%h=linkprop([ax1, ax2],{'CameraPosition', 'CameraUpVector', 'XTick', 'YTick', 'ZTick'});
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


for i=2:size(pointsQRS,1)
    if mod(i,2)==0
        QRS=plot3(pointsQRS([i-1:i],1),pointsQRS([i-1:i],2),pointsQRS([i-1:i],3),'-g','LineWidth',1);
    else
        plot3(pointsQRS([i-1:i],1),pointsQRS([i-1:i],2),pointsQRS([i-1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
    end
end


for i=2:size(pointsT,1)
    if mod(i,2)==0
        T=plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-1:i],3),'-r','LineWidth',1);
    else
        plot3(pointsT([i-1:i],1),pointsT([i-1:i],2),pointsT([i-1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
    end
end

for i=2:size(pointsP,1)
    if mod(i,2)==0
        P=plot3(pointsP([i-1:i],1),pointsP([i-1:i],2),pointsP([i-1:i],3),'-b','LineWidth',1);
    else
        plot3(pointsP([i-1:i],1),pointsP([i-1:i],2),pointsP([i-1:i],3),'Color',[0 0 0],'LineWidth',1);
    end
end

%Use plot3 from Matlab example (fill curve with some data).
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%t = -3*pi:pi/50:3*pi;st = sin(t)*2;ct = cos(t)*2;plot3(ax2, st,ct,t/6)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


xlabel('Vx');ylabel('Vy');zlabel('Vz');

mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[-0.5, 2, -1], 'stemWidth', 0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, -0.5, -1], 'stemWidth', 0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);
mArrow3([1.5 2 -1],[1.5, 2, 1], 'stemWidth', 0.005,'color','red','facealpha',0.3);

text(-0.5, 2, -1, 'Vx','FontSize',12);  
text(1.5, -0.5, -1, 'Vy','FontSize',12); 
text(1.5, 2, 1, 'Vz','FontSize',12);

%view(ax1, 3)
%view(ax2, 3)


%Matalb gives warning message: linkaxes requires 2-D axes as input. Use linkprop for generic property linking.
%call linkprop here instead.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%linkaxes([ax1, ax2])
%h=linkprop([ax1, ax2],{'CameraPosition', 'CameraUpVector', 'XTick', 'YTick', 'ZTick'});

%Don't link CameraPosition - it is linked by "listener" implementation
linkprop([ax1, ax2],{'CameraUpVector', 'XTick', 'YTick', 'ZTick'});
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Add "listener", instead of using linkprop
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
addlistener(ax1, 'CameraPosition', 'PostSet', @Ax1CameraPositionCallback);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Display cameratoolbar
cameratoolbar


function Ax1CameraPositionCallback(src, evnt, ~)
ax1 = evnt.AffectedObject;

fig1 = get(ax1, 'Parent');
userData = get(fig1, 'UserData');
ax2 = userData(2);

%Move the camera of ax2 to be in different position compared to ax1, but keep the same distance from the Target.
cameraTarget = get(ax1, 'CameraTarget');
cameraPosition = get(ax1, 'CameraPosition');

V = cameraPosition - cameraTarget;
newV = V + [-10, 0, 0];
newV = newV/norm(newV)*norm(V);
newCameraPosition = cameraTarget + newV;

set(ax2, 'CameraPosition', newCameraPosition);
```

Comment: I have probably made a misunderstanding, I don't want a seperate control, the control the same, just change the view angle of the curve. 

I have done your suggestion, it is connected, but again, the left 3D curve is smaller and it changes it's size while moving it.

PS: I need to keep the same size, keep the connection, just change the position/view angle of the curve.

Comment: Are you going to have time later today?